# Try-Catch gets in a loop for my Scanner - Java

Tags: java, debugging, while-loop, try-catch

In my java program, I am asking which is the age of the player, if the user writes a string when it was made the question I need to show the error checkError(4) and ask again which is the correct age of the player until the user writes a number.

The problem here is that the code gets in a loop when the age is a string and then always prints the string "Age of the player?". I saw in some websites that it can be solved the problem if in the while statement I use in.hasNextInt() but in this case, I am running the while if "check" is true

How can I solve this issue? Thanks

```
 check = true;
  while (check){
    try { 
        System.out.println("Age of the player?");
        if(in.hasNextInt()){
            edad = in.nextInt();
            if (edad > 6 && edad < 100){
                check = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println(checkError(3));
            }
        } else { }
    } catch(Exception e) { // Edad is a string
        System.out.println(checkError(4));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int edad;
    boolean check = true;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (check) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Age of the player?");
            if (in.hasNext()) {
                String s = in.next(); //read as string
                edad = Integer.parseInt(s, 10); // Convet to int and throw exception if NaN
                if (edad > 6 && edad < 100) {
                    check = false;
                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // Edad is a string
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just easier (I think) to not even play with the **Try/Catch**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int edad = 0;
    boolean check = true;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (check) {
        System.out.println("Age of the player (6 to 100 inclusive)?");
        String s = in.nextLine(); // Get User input
        // Did the User provide an integer numerical value?
        if (!s.matches("\\d+")) {
            // Nope...
            System.err.println("Invalid Entry! (" + s + "). Try Again...");
        }
        // Yup...
        else {
            edad = Integer.parseInt(s, 10);  // Convert it to integer
            if (edad > 6 && edad < 100) {    // Check Range
                check = false;   // is in range. :)
            }
            // Is out of range...
            else {
                System.err.println("Age (" + edad + ") is out of range! Try Again...");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Player's Age Is: --> " + edad);  
}
```

Comment: This is another alternative to do what I was asking but the solution on code is longer than the other one